# Cannot run app on NS 2.3.0

Tags: nativescript

I'm using NS 2.3.0 and when I start `tns run android` (and iOS too), there is an error that says:

`Processing node_modules failed. SyntaxError:/Users/ledinh/Smarp/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-tree/test/fixtures/empty/node_modules/foo/package.json: Unexpected end of input`

This was actually happening to me since 2.2, updating to 2.3 does not solve problem. Even the `tns doctor` said that no issues were detected. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.15.0",
    "babel-types": "6.15.0",
    "babylon": "6.9.2",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.2.3",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5"
  },
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.smarpsocial.smarpshare",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "2.3.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.3.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dummy": "echo yay",
    "ios": "xcproj --project platforms/ios/SmarpShare.xcodeproj touch; xcproj --project platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj touch; tns livesync ios --emulator --watch",
    "test-json-schema": "echo 'Not yet implemented';exit 1;"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "app-data": "file:setup_assets/plugins/app-data",
    "jed": "1.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.1.2",
    "nativescript-appwidget": "file:setup_assets/plugins/nativescript-appwidget",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^1.1.3",
    "nativescript-facebook-login": "^0.2.0",
    "nativescript-fresco": "file:setup_assets/plugins/nativescript-fresco",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-logEntries": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^1.1.0",
    "nativescript-push-notifications": "0.0.15",
    "nativescript-snackbar": "^1.0.3",
    "nativescript-timedatepicker": "file:setup_assets/plugins/timedatepicker",
    "nativescript-zendesk": "file:setup_assets/plugins/nativescript-zendesk",
    "simple-text-parser": "1.0.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.3.0",
    "util": "~0.10.3"
  }
}
```

EDIT 2: I created a sample app and it works, but not for my app

Comment: post your package.json content as this is the most likely reason for your issue. You may try to create new project with tns create myNewApp just to make sure that your setup is ok

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because the platforms / tns-core-modules packages in your app have a lower version than what's specified in package.json.

Can you try following [these instructions](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions)? So:

`$ tns platform remove android
$ tns platform add android
$ tns platform remove ios
$ tns platform add android
$ npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save`

Comment: I did follow these instruction on NS documentation page. I also `tns info` to check and everything is matched with package.json